# "local: not in a function"

Tags: linux, bash, command, sh

We want to send information to the channel in Mattermost, but I get this error in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#start
matterSend() {
  # Lowercase variable names; declare them local
  local endpoint=https://mattermost.ltd/hooks/hash..
  local username=$USER
  # Pro tip: don't use a variable for the payload if it's effectively static
  payload=$(cat <<-__EOF
    payload={
    "username" : "$username",
    "channel" : "Genel_Log",
    "text" : "#### ---\\n| Yedekeleme     | Drive Gönderim       | İşlem ***                               |\\n|:-----------|:-----------:|-----------------------------------------------:|\\n| ${2}       | ${3}        | ${1} :white_check_mark:            |\\n"
    }
__EOF
  )

  echo "CURL: curl -i -X POST -d $payload $endpoint"
  curl -i -X POST -d "$payload" "$endpoint"
}
STRING="Starting.." 
matterSend
```

Result:

> fileName.sh: 5: local: not in a function

What is the reason?

Comment: Might be a problem with the actual contents of line 4.

Comment: Cannot reproduce as shown.

Comment: @glennjackman Tested and connection working